# Use the lowest subtype in a typeclass?

Tags: scala, typeclass, deriving

I have the following code:

```
sealed trait Animal
case class Cat(name: String) extends Animal
case class Dog(name: String) extends Animal

trait Show[A] {
  def show(a: A): String
}

class Processor[A](a: A) {
  def print(implicit S: Show[A]): Unit = println(S.show(a))
}

implicit val showCat: Show[Cat] = c => s"Cat=${c.name}"
implicit val showDog: Show[Dog] = d => s"Dog=${d.name}"

val garfield = Cat("Garfield")
val odie = Dog("Odie")

val myPets = List(garfield, odie)

for (p <- myPets) {
  val processor = new Processor(p)
  processor.print // THIS FAILS AT THE MOMENT
}
```

Does anyone know of a nice way to get that line `processor.print` working?

I can think of 2 solutions:

1. pattern match the `p` in the for loop.
2. create an instance of `Show[Animal]` and pattern match it against all its subtypes.

But I'm wondering if there's a better way of doing this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compile error is

```
could not find implicit value for parameter S: Show[Product with Animal with java.io.Serializable]
```

You can make `Animal` extend `Product` and `Serializable`

```
sealed trait Animal extends Product with Serializable
```

https://typelevel.org/blog/2018/05/09/product-with-serializable.html

Also instead of defining implicit `Show[Animal]` manually

```
implicit val showAnimal: Show[Animal] = {
  case x: Cat => implicitly[Show[Cat]].show(x)
  case x: Dog => implicitly[Show[Dog]].show(x)
  // ...
}
```

you can derive `Show` for sealed traits (having instances for descendants) with [macros](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html)

```
def derive[A]: Show[A] = macro impl[A]

def impl[A: c.WeakTypeTag](c: blackbox.Context): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._
  val typA = weakTypeOf[A]
  val subclasses = typA.typeSymbol.asClass.knownDirectSubclasses
  val cases = subclasses.map{ subclass =>
    cq"x: $subclass => _root_.scala.Predef.implicitly[Show[$subclass]].show(x)"
  }
  q"""
    new Show[$typA] {
      def show(a: $typA): _root_.java.lang.String = a match {
        case ..$cases
      }
    }"""
}

implicit val showAnimal: Show[Animal] = derive[Animal]
```

or [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless)

```
implicit val showCnil: Show[CNil] = _.impossible

implicit def showCcons[H, T <: Coproduct](implicit
  hShow: Show[H],
  tShow: Show[T]
): Show[H :+: T] = _.eliminate(hShow.show, tShow.show)
  
implicit def showGen[A, C <: Coproduct](implicit
  gen: Generic.Aux[A, C],
  show: Show[C]
): Show[A] = a => show.show(gen.to(a))
```

or [Magnolia](https://magnolia.work/opensource/magnolia)

```
object ShowDerivation {
  type Typeclass[T] = Show[T]

  def combine[T](ctx: CaseClass[Show, T]): Show[T] = null

  def dispatch[T](ctx: SealedTrait[Show, T]): Show[T] =
    value => ctx.dispatch(value) { sub =>
      sub.typeclass.show(sub.cast(value))
    }

  implicit def gen[T]: Show[T] = macro Magnolia.gen[T]
}

import ShowDerivation.gen
```

or [Scalaz-deriving](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz-deriving)

```
@scalaz.annotation.deriving(Show)
sealed trait Animal extends Product with Serializable

object Show {
  implicit val showDeriving: Deriving[Show] = new Decidablez[Show] {
    override def dividez[Z, A <: TList, ShowA <: TList](tcs: Prod[ShowA])(
      g: Z => Prod[A]
    )(implicit
      ev: A PairedWith ShowA
    ): Show[Z] = null

    override def choosez[Z, A <: TList, ShowA <: TList](tcs: Prod[ShowA])(
      g: Z => Cop[A]
    )(implicit
      ev: A PairedWith ShowA
    ): Show[Z] = z => {
      val x = g(z).zip(tcs)
      x.b.value.show(x.a)
    }
  }
}
```

For [`cats.Show`](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/cats/Show.scala) with [Kittens](https://github.com/typelevel/kittens) you can write just

```
implicit val showAnimal: Show[Animal] = cats.derived.semi.show
```

The thing is that `garfield` and `odie` in `List(garfield, odie)` have the same type and it's `Animal` instead of `Cat` and `Dog`. If you don't want to define instance of type class for parent type you can use list-like structure preserving types of individual elements, [HList](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#heterogenous-lists) `garfield :: odie :: HNil`.

---

For comparison deriving type classes in Scala 3

[How to access parameter list of case class in a dotty macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62853337/how-to-access-parameter-list-of-case-class-in-a-dotty-macro)

Comment: In Magnolia 1.1.2 `join` is instead of `combine`, `split` is instead of `dispatch` https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/05e9N9PLRba9htqVZGW1CA/1 `libraryDependencies += "com.softwaremill.magnolia1_2" %% "magnolia" % "1.1.2"` https://github.com/softwaremill/magnolia/tree/scala2 https://github.com/softwaremill/magnolia

Comment: https://github.com/propensive/wisteria

Comment: https://github.com/propensive/adversaria/

Answer (score 1):

The most general solution is to just pack the typeclass instances in at the creation of `myPets`, existentially

```
final case class Packaged[+T, +P](wit: T, prf: P)
type WithInstance[T, +P[_ <: T]] = Packaged[U, P[U]] forSome { type U <: T }
implicit def packageInstance[T, U <: T, P[_ <: T]]
                            (wit: U)(implicit prf: P[U])
                          : T WithInstance P
= Packaged(wit, prf)

val myPets = List[Animal WithInstance Show](garfield, odie)
for(Packaged(p, showP) <- myPets) {
    implicit val showP1 = showP
    new Processor(p).print // note: should be def print()(implicit S: Show[A]), so that this can be .print()
}
```

Comment: Nice approach. It's sad this will not work in Scala 3 (because of lack of existential types). Just curious, what do names `wit` and `prf` mean?

Comment: @DmytroMitin `wit`ness and `pr`oo`f`. You have some "real values" type `T` (a witness) along with some "proof" or "testimony" of some property `P`, such as `Show`ability. This will work just fine in Scala 3 with some tweaks. `sealed trait WithInstance[T, +P[_ <: T]] { type U <: T; val wit: U; val prf: P[U] }; object WithInstance { implicit def apply[T, V <: T, P[_ <: T]](wit0: V)(implicit prf0: P[V]): T WithInstance P = new WithInstance[T, P] { type U = V; val wit = wit0; val prf = prf0 }; def unapply[T, P[_ <: T]](wi: T WithInstance P): Some[(wi.U, P[wi.U])] = Some((wi.wit, wi.prf)) }`