# How to access parameter list of case class in a dotty macro

Tags: scala, reflection, metaprogramming, scala-macros, dotty

I am trying to learn meta-programming in dotty. Specifically compile time code generation. I thought learning by building something would be a good approach. So I decided to make a CSV parser which will parse lines into case classes. I want to use dotty macros to generate decoders

```
trait Decoder[T]{
  def decode(str:String):Either[ParseError, T]
}

object Decoder {
  inline given stringDec as Decoder[String] = new Decoder[String] {
    override def decode(str: String): Either[ParseError, String] = Right(str)
  }

  inline given intDec as Decoder[Int] = new Decoder[Int] {
    override def decode(str: String): Either[ParseError, Int] =
      str.toIntOption.toRight(ParseError(str, "value is not valid Int"))
  }
  
  inline def forType[T]:Decoder[T] = ${make[T]}

  def make[T:Type](using qctx: QuoteContext):Expr[Decoder[T]] = ???
}
```

I have provided basic decoders for `Int` & `String`, now I looking for guidance for `def make[T:Type]` method. How to iterate parameter list of a case class `T` inside this method? Are there any recommended ways or patterns to do this?

Comment: https://users.scala-lang.org/t/how-to-access-parameter-list-of-case-class-in-a-dotty-macro/6358

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using standard [type class derivation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/contextual/derivation.html) in Dotty

```scala
import scala.deriving.Mirror

case class ParseError(str: String, msg: String)

trait Decoder[T]{
  def decode(str:String): Either[ParseError, T]
}

object Decoder {
  given Decoder[String] with {
    override def decode(str: String): Either[ParseError, String] = Right(str)
  }

  given Decoder[Int] with {
    override def decode(str: String): Either[ParseError, Int] =
      str.toIntOption.toRight(ParseError(str, "value is not valid Int"))
  }

  inline def derived[T](using m: Mirror.Of[T]): Decoder[T] = {
    val elemInstances = summonAll[m.MirroredElemTypes]
    inline m match {
      case p: Mirror.ProductOf[T] => productDecoder(p, elemInstances)
      case s: Mirror.SumOf[T]     => ???
    }
  }

  inline def summonAll[T <: Tuple]: List[Decoder[?]] =
    compiletime.summonAll[Tuple.Map[T, Decoder]].toList.asInstanceOf[List[Decoder[?]]]

  def productDecoder[T](p: Mirror.ProductOf[T], elems: List[Decoder[?]]): Decoder[T] =
    new Decoder[T] {
      def decode(str: String): Either[ParseError, T] = {
        val strs = str.split(',')
        if (strs.isEmpty) Left(ParseError(str, "nothing to split"))
        else elems.zip(strs)
          .traverse(_.decode(_))
          .map(ts => p.fromProduct(Tuple.fromArray(ts.toArray)))
      }
    }

  extension [E,A,B](es: List[A])
    def traverse(f: A => Either[E, B]): Either[E, List[B]] =
      es.foldRight[Either[E, List[B]]](Right(Nil))((h, tRes) => map2(f(h), tRes)(_ :: _))

  def map2[E, A, B, C](a: Either[E, A], b: Either[E, B])(f: (A, B) => C): Either[E, C] =
    for { a1 <- a; b1 <- b } yield f(a1,b1)
}

case class A(i: Int, s: String) derives Decoder

println(summon[Decoder[A]].decode("10,abc"))//Right(A(10,abc))
println(summon[Decoder[A]].decode("xxx,abc"))//Left(ParseError(xxx,value is not valid Int))
println(summon[Decoder[A]].decode(",,"))//Left(ParseError(,,,nothing to split))
```

Tested in 3.2.0.

---

Using [Shapeless-3](https://github.com/typelevel/shapeless-3)

```
import shapeless3.deriving.K0
import shapeless3.typeable.Typeable

case class ParseError(str: String, msg: String)

trait Decoder[T]{
  def decode(str:String): Either[ParseError, T]
}

object Decoder {
  inline given stringDec: Decoder[String] = new Decoder[String] {
    override def decode(str: String): Either[ParseError, String] = Right(str)
  }

  inline given intDec: Decoder[Int] = new Decoder[Int] {
    override def decode(str: String): Either[ParseError, Int] =
      str.toIntOption.toRight(ParseError(str, "value is not valid Int"))
  }

  inline def derived[A](using gen: K0.Generic[A]): Decoder[A] =
    gen.derive(productDecoder, null)

  given productDecoder[T](using inst: K0.ProductInstances[Decoder, T], typeable: Typeable[T]): Decoder[T] = new Decoder[T] {
    def decode(str: String): Either[ParseError, T] = {
      type Acc = (List[String], Option[ParseError])
      inst.unfold[Acc](str.split(',').toList, None)([t] => (acc: Acc, dec: Decoder[t]) =>
        acc._1 match {
          case head :: tail => dec.decode(head) match {
            case Right(t) => ((tail, None), Some(t))
            case Left(e)  => ((Nil, Some(e)), None)
          }
          case Nil => (acc, None)
        }
      ) match {
        case ((_, Some(e)), None) => Left(e)
        case ((_, None), None)    => Left(ParseError(str, s"value is not valid ${typeable.describe}"))
        case (_, Some(t))         => Right(t)
      }
    }
  }
}

case class A(i: Int, s: String) derives Decoder

@main def test = {
  println(summon[Decoder[A]].decode("10,abc")) //Right(A(10,abc))
  println(summon[Decoder[A]].decode("xxx,abc")) //Left(ParseError(xxx,value is not valid Int))
  println(summon[Decoder[A]].decode(",")) //Left(ParseError(,,value is not valid A))
}
```

*build.sbt*

```
scalaVersion := "3.2.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.typelevel" %% "shapeless3-deriving" % "3.2.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.typelevel" %% "shapeless3-typeable" % "3.2.0"
```

---

Using [Dotty macros](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/metaprogramming/macros.html) + [TASTy reflection](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/metaprogramming/reflection.html) like in [dotty-macro-examples/macroTypeclassDerivation](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty-macro-examples/tree/main/macroTypeClassDerivation) (this approach is even more low-level than the one with `scala.deriving.Mirror`)

```
import scala.quoted.*

case class ParseError(str: String, msg: String)

trait Decoder[T]{
  def decode(str: String): Either[ParseError, T]
}

object Decoder {
  inline given Decoder[String] with {
    override def decode(str: String): Either[ParseError, String] = Right(str)
  }

  inline given Decoder[Int] with {
    override def decode(str: String): Either[ParseError, Int] =
      str.toIntOption.toRight(ParseError(str, "value is not valid Int"))
  }

  inline def derived[T]: Decoder[T] = ${ derivedImpl[T] }

  def derivedImpl[T](using Quotes, Type[T]): Expr[Decoder[T]] = {
    import quotes.reflect.*
    val tpeSym = TypeRepr.of[T].typeSymbol
    if (tpeSym.flags.is(Flags.Case)) productDecoder[T]
    else if (tpeSym.flags.is(Flags.Trait & Flags.Sealed)) ???
    else sys.error(s"Unsupported combination of flags: ${tpeSym.flags.show}")
  }

  def productDecoder[T](using Quotes, Type[T]): Expr[Decoder[T]] = {
    import quotes.reflect.*
    val fields: List[Symbol]             = TypeRepr.of[T].typeSymbol.caseFields
    val fieldTypeTrees: List[TypeTree]   = fields.map(_.tree.asInstanceOf[ValDef].tpt)
    val decoderTerms: List[Term]         = fieldTypeTrees.map(lookupDecoderFor(_))
    val decoders: Expr[List[Decoder[_]]] = Expr.ofList(decoderTerms.map(_.asExprOf[Decoder[_]]))

    def mkT(fields: Expr[List[_]]): Expr[T] = {
      Apply(
        Select.unique(New(TypeTree.of[T]), "<init>"),
        fieldTypeTrees.zipWithIndex.map((fieldType, i) =>
          TypeApply(
            Select.unique(
              Apply(
                Select.unique(
                  fields.asTerm,
                  "apply"),
                List(Literal(IntConstant(i)))
              ), "asInstanceOf"),
            List(fieldType)
          )
        )
      ).asExprOf[T]
    }

    '{
      new Decoder[T]{
        override def decode(str: String): Either[ParseError, T] = {
          val strs = str.split(',').toList
          if (strs.isEmpty) Left(ParseError(str, "nothing to split"))
          else $decoders.zip(strs).traverse(_.decode(_)).map(fields =>
            ${mkT('fields)}
          )
        }
      }
    }
  }

  def lookupDecoderFor(using Quotes)(t: quotes.reflect.Tree): quotes.reflect.Term = {
    import quotes.reflect.*
    val tpe: TypeTree = Applied(TypeTree.of[Decoder], List(t))
    Implicits.search(tpe.tpe) match {
      case res: ImplicitSearchSuccess => res.tree
    }
  }

  extension [E,A,B](es: List[A]) {
    def traverse(f: A => Either[E, B]): Either[E, List[B]] =
      es.foldRight[Either[E, List[B]]](Right(Nil))((h, tRes) => map2(f(h), tRes)(_:: _))
  }

  def map2[E, A, B, C](a: Either[E, A], b: Either[E, B])(f: (A, B) => C): Either[E, C] =
    for { a1 <- a; b1 <- b } yield f(a1,b1)
}

case class A(i: Int, s: String) derives Decoder

@main def test = {
  println(summon[Decoder[A]].decode("10,abc"))//Right(A(10,abc))
  println(summon[Decoder[A]].decode("xxx,abc"))//Left(ParseError(xxx,value is not valid Int))
  println(summon[Decoder[A]].decode(","))//Left(ParseError(,,nothing to split))
}
```

Tested in 3.2.0.

---

We can implement `Generic` like in Scala 2/Shapeless 2

[Scala 3 collection partitioning with subtypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69483366/scala-3-collection-partitioning-with-subtypes)

```scala
import scala.deriving.Mirror

trait Generic[T] {
  type Repr
  def to(t: T): Repr
  def from(r: Repr): T
}

object Generic {
  type Aux[T, Repr0] = Generic[T] {type Repr = Repr0}

  def instance[T, Repr0](f: T => Repr0, g: Repr0 => T): Aux[T, Repr0] =
    new Generic[T] {
      override type Repr = Repr0
      override def to(t: T): Repr0 = f(t)
      override def from(r: Repr0): T = g(r)
    }

  object ops {
    extension[A] (a: A) {
      def toRepr(using g: Generic[A]): g.Repr = g.to(a)
    }

    extension[Repr] (a: Repr) {
      def to[A](using g: Generic.Aux[A, Repr]): A = g.from(a)
    }
  }

  given [T <: Product](using
    m: Mirror.ProductOf[T],
    m1: Mirror.ProductOf[m.MirroredElemTypes]
  ): Aux[T, m.MirroredElemTypes] = instance(
    m1.fromProduct(_),
    m.fromProduct(_)
  )
}
```

and derive the type class with `Generic`

```scala
case class ParseError(str: String, msg: String)

trait Decoder[T]{
  def decode(str:String): Either[ParseError, T]
}

object Decoder {
  given Decoder[String] with {
    override def decode(str: String): Either[ParseError, String] = Right(str)
  }

  given Decoder[Int] with {
    override def decode(str: String): Either[ParseError, Int] =
      str.toIntOption.toRight(ParseError(str, "value is not valid Int"))
  }

  given Decoder[EmptyTuple] with {
    override def decode(str: String): Either[ParseError, EmptyTuple] =
      Either.cond(str.isEmpty, EmptyTuple, ParseError(str, "not empty string"))
  }

  given [H, T <: Tuple](using hDecoder: Decoder[H], tDecoder: Decoder[T]): Decoder[H *: T] with {
    override def decode(str: String): Either[ParseError, H *: T] = for {
      h <- hDecoder.decode(str.takeWhile(_ != ','))
      t <- tDecoder.decode(str.dropWhile(_ != ',').stripPrefix(","))
    } yield h *: t
  }

  given [T](using gen: Generic[T], decoder: Decoder[gen.Repr]): Decoder[T] with {
    override def decode(str: String): Either[ParseError, T] = decoder.decode(str).map(gen.from)
  }
}

case class A(i: Int, s: String)

println(summon[Decoder[A]].decode("10,abc"))//Right(A(10,abc))
println(summon[Decoder[A]].decode("xxx,abc"))//Left(ParseError(xxx,value is not valid Int))
println(summon[Decoder[A]].decode("10,abc,xxx"))//Left(ParseError(xxx,not empty string))
println(summon[Decoder[A]].decode(",,"))//Left(ParseError(,value is not valid Int))
```

Tested in 3.2.0.

---

For comparison deriving type classes in Scala 2

[Use the lowest subtype in a typeclass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61392874/use-the-lowest-subtype-in-a-typeclass/)

Comment: Thanks for such a thoughtful and detailed answer. Unfortunately it is not compiling for me  .  Here's what I get: https://ibb.co/RS67cWB

Comment: The resources you have linked are very useful. I will go through to better understand the concepts .

Comment: @BilalFazlani Something seems to change :) This code compiles in 0.24.0. But in 0.25.0-RC2 it produces "cannot reduce inline match".

Comment: Ahh no worries. I will switch to 0.24 for now :)

Comment: I had to make two small changes to make it work. 
First - `case EmptyTuple => Nil` instead of `case Unit => Nil` in def summonAll.
Second - had to reverse the array `new ArrayProduct(ts.toArray.reverse))`

Dont know why

Comment: I mean in dotty 0.25

Comment: @BilalFazlani Great! Meanwhile I added code with Shapeless-3 (currently in 0.24 only, because Shapeless-3 hasn't been published for 0.25).

Comment: @BilalFazlani `Unit -> EmptyTuple` was a change 0.24 -> 0.25. `reverse` was my bug, I didn't test parse error case. Good catch!

Comment: Thanks so much! I will study and try to understand this as well. btw, I am very curious to know - when to use standard typeclass derivation in dotty and when to use shapeless 3?

Comment: @BilalFazlani Shapeless-3 derivation is based on standard Dotty derivation (unlike Shapeless-2 where derivation is macro-based while Scala 2 doesn't have standard derivation mechanism). I would say that Shapeless-3 approach is more high-level and standard Dotty approach is more low-level. Although in this specific case it's not obvious.

Comment: @BilalFazlani In my first approach `summon[Decoder[A]].decode(",")` still explodes.

Comment: Understood. Thank you!  :)

Comment: @BilalFazlani It's not necessary to do `.reverse`. My `traverse` was buggy, `foldRight` should be instead of `foldLeft` :)

Comment: Ohh yes, that makes sense 

Comment: @BilalFazlani I added code with Dotty macros. This approach is even more low-level than the one with `scala.deriving.Mirror`.

Comment: Thanks for keeping this answer up to date. This is helpful for many.