# scala 3 macro how to implement generic trait

Tags: scala, dotty, scala-3

I want to implement a `proxy` of some trait `A` (e.g. delegates method call to some rpc call), like this

```
   def clientProxy[A](using Type[A], Quotes): Expr[A] = {
    import quotes.reflect._
    val defTrees: List[Tree] = TypeRepr.of[A].typeSymbol.memberFields.collect {
      case mf if mf.isDefDef =>
        ???
    }

    val exprs = Expr.ofList(defTrees.map(_.asExpr))
    '{
      new A {
        $exprs
      }
    }
  }
```

But the compiler complains

```
A is not a class type
```

Answer (score 1):

If `A` were a class you could try to replace

```
'{
  new A {
    $exprs
  }
}
```

with

```
Apply(
  Select.unique(New(TypeTree.of[A]), "<init>"),
  defTrees.map(_.asExpr.asTerm)
).asExprOf[A]
```

(Scala 3.0.0-RC1-bin-20210106-e39b79e-NIGHTLY)

[How to access parameter list of case class in a dotty macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62853337/how-to-access-parameter-list-of-case-class-in-a-dotty-macro/)

Now since `A` is a trait, I guess you should define a class implementing this trait and try similar thing for this class

**[Method Override with Scala 3 Macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68550985/method-override-with-scala-3-macros) (since Scala 3.1.3)**

Comment: There is an anonymous  class here.  As this  https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty-feature-requests/issues/153 states