# Getting MirroredElemLabels from Mirror

Tags: scala, generics, shapeless, type-level-computation, scala-3

Scala 3's `scala.deriving.Mirror` has a type member [`MirroredElemLabels`](https://dotty.epfl.ch/api/scala/deriving/Mirror.html#MirroredElemLabels-0) which is a tuple of string literals. What's the standard way to get that type as a value?

EDIT: [here's the code](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/4tfGCYJcSxafZr1mbmayEw) that produces a compiler error from trying to use `summonAll`

```
case class Test(a: Int, b: String)
val mirror = implicitly[Mirror.ProductOf[Test]]
val labels = summonAll[mirror.MirroredElemLabels]
println(labels)
```

---

```
cannot reduce inline match with
 scrutinee:  compiletime.erasedValue[App.mirror.MirroredElemLabels] : App.mirror.MirroredElemLabels
 patterns :  case _:EmptyTuple
             case _:*:[t @ _, ts @ _]
```

Comment: http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/contextual/derivation.html https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62853337/how-to-access-parameter-list-of-case-class-in-a-dotty-macro/

Comment: @DmytroMitin I had seen those docs, this is what I had reduced it down to https://scastie.scala-lang.org/4tfGCYJcSxafZr1mbmayEw but I'm not sure where to go from this compiler error

Comment: `implicitly[Mirror.ProductOf[Test]]` is correct. But `summonAll[mirror.MirroredElemLabels]` is incorrect. It's true that `implicitly[mirror.MirroredElemLabels =:= ("i", "s")]` but it doesn't mean that there is an implicit of type `mirror.MirroredElemLabels` or implicits of singleton types `"i"`, `"s"`. This type `mirror.MirroredElemLabels` is a tuple of singleton types. And you probably want to find a value tuple consisting of values of these singleton types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `scala.ValueOf`

```
case class A(i: Int, s: String)

import scala.deriving.Mirror
import scala.compiletime.summonAll

val mirror = summon[Mirror.Of[A]]    
type ValueOfs = Tuple.Map[mirror.MirroredElemLabels, ValueOf]
val valueOfs = summonAll[ValueOfs]

def values(t: Tuple): Tuple = t match
  case (h: ValueOf[_]) *: t1 => h.value *: values(t1)
  case EmptyTuple => EmptyTuple

values(valueOfs) // (i,s)
```

---

We can now use `scala.compiletime.constValueTuple`

```
inline def constValueTuple[T <: Tuple]: T =
  (inline erasedValue[T] match
    case _: EmptyTuple => EmptyTuple
    case _: (t *: ts) => constValue[t] *: constValueTuple[ts]
  ).asInstanceOf[T]
```

and the return type will be precise

```
case class A(i: Int, s: String)

val mirror = summon[Mirror.Of[A]]

val res = constValueTuple[mirror.MirroredElemLabels] // (i,s)

res: ("i", "s") // compiles
```

Tested in 3.2.0

https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/contextual/derivation.html

https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/metaprogramming/compiletime-ops.html

Comment: One thing to note explicitly for anyone else who finds this: you need to use `summon` instead of `implicitly` for the mirror, or else it will not compile

Comment: follow up question, is there a way to get `values` to return a correct type? This is what I'm working on so far https://scastie.scala-lang.org/dZfa6p7TRN66Ek2XcekNgw. It seems the compiler can't recognize equivalence of two match types

Comment: The cheat way to get our final solution typed would be to just add `.asInstanceOf[mirror.MirroredElemLabels]` to the return of the call to `values`

Comment: @kag0 Yeah, match types not always work well so far along with corresponding pattern matching on value level http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/new-types/match-types.html#dependent-typing For example calculations on type level along with calculations on value level can be done type-safely with good old type classes (as an alternative to match types).

Comment: @kag0 We can now use `scala.compiletime.constValueTuple` and the return type will be precise. See update.