# Using K0.ProductInstances in shapeless3

Tags: scala, shapeless, scala-3

I have a library with typeclasses that I am migrating to Scala 3 using shapeless-3. One of my typeclasses is:

```scala
trait Parser[T] {

  def parse(ctx: Context): (Option[T], Context)

}
```

where `Option[T]` represents an optionally parsed `T` and `Context` wraps the parsing state (e.g. index in a string)

I define some `givens` for primitive and basic types and eventually have to define a `defaultGen` for products:

```scala
given defaultGen[T](using inst: K0.ProductInstances[Parser, T]): Parser[T] with
  def parse(ctx: Context) = ???
```

What should I replace `???` with? I tried `inst.construct`, `inst.map` but I am unable to make it work without having the compiler complaining with errors such as:

```
[error] 399 |    def parse(ctx: Context) = inst.construct([t] => (p: Parser[t]) => p.parse(ctx))
[error]     |                                                                                  ^
[error]     |   Found:    [t] => (sweet.delights.parsing.Parser[t]) => (Option[t],
[error]     |     sweet.delights.parsing.Context
[error]     |   )
[error]     |   Required: [t] => (sweet.delights.parsing.Parser[t²]) => t²
[error]     |
[error]     |   where:    t  is a type variable
[error]     |             t² is a type variable with constraint
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type mismatch means that you should use not `construct`. Try `unfold`

```
given defaultGen[T](using inst: K0.ProductInstances[Parser, T]): Parser[T] with
  def parse(ctx: Context) = inst.unfold[Context](ctx)(
    [t] => (c: Context, p: Parser[t]) => p.parse(c).swap
  ).swap
```

See other examples:

[How to access parameter list of case class in a dotty macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62853337/how-to-access-parameter-list-of-case-class-in-a-dotty-macro)

https://github.com/typelevel/shapeless-3/blob/main/modules/deriving/src/test/scala/shapeless3/deriving/type-classes.scala

https://github.com/satabin/fs2-data/blob/main/csv/generic/shared/src/main/scala-3/fs2/data/csv/generic/semiauto.scala